# Python - Cannot match value from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

```
import random

dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
print(dice1, dice2)

user_in = "Odd"
odd = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
even = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]

def cho_han(dice1, dice2, money1, user_in):
  if (dice1 + dice2 == odd) and user_input == "Odd":
    return "Odd! You Won $" + str(money1 * 2)
  elif (dice1 + dice2 == odd) and user_in != "Odd":
    return "Odd! You lost $" + str(money1)
  elif (dice1 + dice2 == even) and user_in == "Even":
    return "Even! You Won $" + str(money1 * 2)
  else:
    return "Even! You lost $" + str(money1)

print(cho_han(dice1, dice2, 300, user_in))
```

No matter what I put in for the variable `user_in` it will always print `"Even! You lost $300"`
Sorry for having such a minor problem I'm new to python and programming in general and am just trying to learn.

Thanks for anyone who can help!

Comment: That might be because an integer `dice1 + dice2` is never equal [`==`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) to a list such as `odd` or `even`. Were you trying to use [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)?

Comment: Look at `dice1 + dice2 == odd`. With `dice1 + dice2` you create an integer value and check if it is the same as the list `odd`. That's impossible. You want to check if the value is in the list: `(dice1 + dice2) in odd`.

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you! This helped clarify solve the problem and help me learn :)

Comment: BTW, it doesn't matter here but if you have bigger lookup lists you might want to use a `set` instead. `odd = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]` vs. `odd = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11}`. Lookup in lists is O(N) while lookups in sets are O(1). If you don't know this notation: Lookups in sets are faster.

Answer (score 1):

Notice `dice1 + dice2 in odd`, integer value cannot be equal to list.

```
def cho_han(dice1, dice2, money1, user_in):
    if (dice1 + dice2 in odd) and user_in == "Odd":
        return "Odd! You Won $" + str(money1 * 2)
    elif (dice1 + dice2 in odd) and user_in != "Odd":
        return "Odd! You lost $" + str(money1)
    elif (dice1 + dice2 in even) and user_in == "Even":
        return "Even! You Won $" + str(money1 * 2)
    else:
        return "Even! You lost $" + str(money1)
```

Comment: typo in if statement user_input

Comment: Yeah! Thanks @Vikas

Answer (score 0):

I would like make following changes to the code:

- Parity (even or odd) is binary. It doesn't have to be a string input
- Get rid of lookup table as it will not scale very well
- Put the code in a function that can be called again and tested easily
- Move call to random in another function and call it inside `cho_han`

restructure this write this code

```
import random

def get_dices():
    dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print(dice1, dice2)
    return dice1, dice2

user_in = "Odd"
user_parity = True if user_in.lower() == 'even' else False

def cho_han(money1, user_parity):
    dice1, dice2 = get_dices()
    result_parity = (dice1 + dice2) % 2 == 0
    result_parity_str = "Even" if result_parity else "Odd"

    if result_parity == user_parity:
        return "{}! You Won {}".format(result_parity_str, str(money1))
    else:
        return "{}! You lost {}".format(result_parity_str, str(money1))

print(cho_han(300, user_parity))
```

If you decide to test you code, you can [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) `get_dices()`.